Combine rows values based on same date sql
In the example I am providing, I am trying to combine time_taken for the month where a value overlaps to 2 days for a month.
SELECT
run_date,
max(end_time) - min(start_time) as time_taken
from bpc_bill_proc_cont
where run_date between '01/01/2024' and today
group by 1
order by 1

output:
03/01/2024         0 00:51:30
04/01/2024         0 01:27:09
04/02/2024         0 01:36:36
03/03/2024         0 00:56:59
04/03/2024         0 01:43:19
03/04/2024         0 00:58:12
04/04/2024         0 01:47:26
03/05/2024         0 00:33:06
04/05/2024         0 01:08:30
04/06/2024         0 01:16:37
03/07/2024         0 00:34:21
04/07/2024         0 01:12:52
03/08/2024         0 00:48:39
04/08/2024         0 01:08:56

My expected output must be something like below:
01/2024         0 02:18:39
02/2024         0 01:36:36
03/2024         0 02:40:18
04/2024         0 02:45:28
05/2024         0 01:41:36
06/2024         0 01:16:37
07/2024         0 01:12:52
08/2024         0 01:57:35

I am struggling how to go about this and need some guidance.

I guess you are using the European-style dd/mm/yyyy format for dates, but all the example dates are ambiguous between that and the US-style mm/dd/yyyy format.  I think it is best to use the ISO 8601 format — yyyy-mm-dd — as it is unambiguous.  It also helps if you include a minimal schema and sample data for the question (and couch the expected output in terms of the sample data).

Since your output has values like 0 01:57:35, I suppose that the end_time and start_time columns must have the type DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND (or, at least, a maximal unit of YEAR, MONTH or DAY), so that the output type for the difference is an INTERVAL DAY(9) TO FRACTION type.  This is the sort of issue that would be a non-issue if the question included the relevant schema and data.

The correct total time taken for July, given the input data, should surely be 1:47:13 rather than 1:12:52.

I tried many options by casting the dates and converting to EPOCH for adding the months values together and still no luck. I managed to use the below I put together, however it does give what I want, but I would like to combine the year and month columns into 1 column
SELECT 
YEAR(run_date) AS year,
MONTH(run_date) AS month,
SUM((seconds) units second)::interval hour(2) to second AS time_taken
FROM (
SELECT run_date,
(MAX(end_time)- MIN(start_time))::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER AS seconds
FROM bpc_bill_proc_cont
where run_date BETWEEN '01/01/2024' AND TODAY
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2 ASC

Output:
year  month time_taken

2024      1   2:18:39
2024      2   1:36:36
2024      3   2:40:18
2024      4   2:45:38
2024      5   1:41:36
2024      6   1:16:37
2024      7   1:47:13
2024      8   1:57:35

If you can find a more sufficient way of re-writing the sql then I open to ideas thanks.
What I would like to see is the below output:
Date        time_taken

1/2024      2:18:39
2/2024      1:36:36
3/2024      2:40:18
4/2024      2:45:38
5/2024      1:41:36
6/2024      1:16:37
7/2024      1:47:13
8/2024      1:57:35


Only way I see it can be done:
SELECT
month || '/' || year AS month_year,
time_taken
FROM (
SELECT 
YEAR(run_date) AS year,
MONTH(run_date) AS month,
SUM((seconds) units second)::interval hour(2) to second AS time_taken
FROM (
SELECT run_date,
(MAX(end_time)- MIN(start_time))::INTERVAL SECOND(9) TO SECOND::VARCHAR(10)::INTEGER AS seconds
FROM bpc_bill_proc_cont
where run_date BETWEEN '01/01/2024' AND TODAY
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
)
GROUP BY 1,2
ORDER BY 2 ASC)


I'm assuming this schema:
CREATE TABLE bpc_bill_proc_cont
(
    run_date    DATE NOT NULL,
    start_time  DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND NOT NULL,
    end_time    DATETIME HOUR TO SECOND,
    CHECK(end_time IS NULL OR (end_time > start_time))
);

And since we weren't given any detailed breakdown of the input data, I'm using this input data, derived from the output, and using the ISO 8601 (aka ISO 90-75 TIME and TIMESTAMP) format: YYYY-MM-DD.  I'm using a start time of midnight and the end time as the 'time taken' value given in the output for the sample query:
2024-01-03|00:00:00|00:51:30
2024-01-04|00:00:00|01:27:09
2024-02-04|00:00:00|01:36:36
2024-03-03|00:00:00|00:56:59
2024-03-04|00:00:00|01:43:19
2024-04-03|00:00:00|00:58:12
2024-04-04|00:00:00|01:47:26
2024-05-03|00:00:00|00:33:06
2024-05-04|00:00:00|01:08:30
2024-06-04|00:00:00|01:16:37
2024-07-03|00:00:00|00:34:21
2024-07-04|00:00:00|01:12:52
2024-08-03|00:00:00|00:48:39
2024-08-04|00:00:00|01:08:56

The example query reproduces the expected output, give or take the formatting of the date.
It is simple to use a CTE (common table expression) to produce the desired output:
WITH per_day_usage(run_date, run_month, time_taken) AS
    (SELECT run_date,
            EXTEND(run_date, YEAR TO MONTH) AS run_month,
            MAX(end_time) - MIN(start_time) AS time_taken
       FROM bpc_bill_proc_cont
      WHERE run_date BETWEEN MDY(01,01,2024) AND TODAY
      GROUP BY run_date
    )
SELECT run_month, SUM(time_taken) AS time_taken
  FROM per_day_usage
 GROUP BY run_month
 ORDER BY run_month;

The output is:
2024-01|2:18:39
2024-02|1:36:36
2024-03|2:40:18
2024-04|2:45:38
2024-05|1:41:36
2024-06|1:16:37
2024-07|1:47:13
2024-08|1:57:35

The first column has the type DATETIME YEAR TO MONTH and the second column has the type INTERVAL DAY(9) TO SECOND.
If you're using an older version of Informix without support for CTEs, you can use this query instead, which produces the same output.
SELECT run_month, SUM(time_taken) AS time_taken
  FROM (SELECT run_date,
               EXTEND(run_date, YEAR TO MONTH) AS run_month,
               MAX(end_time) - MIN(start_time) AS time_taken
          FROM bpc_bill_proc_cont
         WHERE run_date BETWEEN MDY(01,01,2024) AND TODAY
         GROUP BY run_date
       ) AS per_day_usage
 GROUP BY run_month
 ORDER BY run_month;

You shouldn't be using a version of Informix so old it doesn't run either of these, but if you are, you can create an explicit temporary table to hold the result of the CTE or sub-query and then run a statement to summarize that temporary table.
